# Behavior Subject with Buttons

Tags: angular, service, rxjs

I am trying to have a component appear when I click on a button. The component and the button are in two unrelated classes so I am using the Behavior Subject module. However, the link between the button and the service will not change the boolean value to "true" and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code:

Data.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{

    private showEventForm = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    currentShowEventForm = this.showEventForm.asObservable();

    constructor(){ }

    editShowEventForm(newClick){
        this.showEventForm.next(newClick);
    }

}
```

Html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toggleEventForm()">
Post Event</button>
```

Ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'vhub-postEvent',
  templateUrl: './postevent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./postevent.component.css"]
})
export class PostEventComponent implements OnInit{
  showEventForm: boolean = false;

  constructor(private mydata: DataService) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.mydata.currentShowEventForm.subscribe(showEventForm => this.showEventForm = showEventForm);

  }
  toggleEventForm(): void{
    this.showEventForm = !this.showEventForm;
  }

}
```

Comment: *The component and the button are in two unrelated classes*: and yet, the method toggleEventForm called when the button is clicked and the subscription to the subject are in the same class. You've shown a single component. And you haven't shown the place where the component is supposed to be shown or hidden. You also never call the editShowEventForm method of the service anywhere. Post a complete example in a stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `showEventForm` data to your service in order to change `BehaviorSubject` value.

```
toggleEventForm(): void{
    this.showEventForm = !this.showEventForm;
    this.mydata.editShowEventForm(this.showEventForm);
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you :) May I ask you you to mark the answer as accepted if that worked for you, please?